# Discrete proof?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

So we're doing proofs regarding numbers in discrete and I'm unsure of form. Is there anyone who could help me through this?

Prove $n^2 + 2n +1$ is odd for all even integers, then prove that it is odd for all integers.

Comment: It will be easier to get answers if you show your work so far.

Comment: The statement "odd for all integers" is clearly wrong. When $n=1$ it produces an even value. I think it meant "even for all odd integers".

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $n^2+2n+1=(n+1)^2$.

- What happens if $n$ is even, or more explicit $n=2k$, in which $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.
- What happens if $n$ is odd, or more explicit $n=2k+1$, in which $k \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: I get that that comes to (2k+1)^2, but can I call the proof done there since it follows the definition of an odd number being n=2k+1?

Comment: You have to think about the product. What happens if you multiply an odd number with an odd number?

Comment: You'd get an odd number...?

Comment: Yes, that should complete the proof. You could also try this problem with modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1):

You have two cases:

- if $n$ is even, then there exists $k$ such that $n=2k$. Then

$$n^2+2n+1=4k^2+4k+1=2K+1$$

with $K=2k^2+2k\in\mathbb Z$ so $n^2+2n+1$ is odd.

- if $n$ is odd, then there exists $k$ such that $n=2k+1$. Then

$$n^2+2n+1=4k^2+4k+1+4k+2+1=2K$$

with a $K\in \mathbb Z$ well chosen, so $n^2+2n+1$ is even.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig Thanks, it's been corrected.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to prove it's odd for all even integers, substitute an even number for $n$, like $2m$, and see if you can put it in a form $2k+1$.

$n^2+2n+1$

$(2m)^2+2(2m)+1$

$4m^2+4m+1$

$2(2m^2+2m)+1$

$2k+1$, where $k=2m^2+2m$

$n^2+2n+1$ is odd for all even integers.

Then to prove it's even for all odd integers, you just need to follow a similar procedure.